# Scala.js @JSGlobal - cannot perform run sbt

Tags: scala, three.js, sbt, scala.js

I'm struggling with an error and I cannot think of good solution.

I have class:

```
@JSGlobal("THREE.Scene")
class Scene extends js.Object {
  def add(obj: js.Object): Unit = ???
}
```

and main:

```
[...]
    val scene = new Scene()
[...]
    scene.add(cube)
[...]
```

When I perform in sbt:

```
fastOptJS
```

and run my html page it all works great but problem comes when I want to run it with sbt:

```
run
```

Then I get error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Scene' of undefined
```

I've tried to replace:

```
@JSGlobal("THREE.Scene")
```

with

```
@JSExportTopLevel("THREE.Scene")
```

It run well when performed **run** in sbt but scene coudn't load on html page with error (in js console) saying that i do not have constructor (for Scene).

I do have in my build.sbt

```
jsEnv := new org.scalajs.jsenv.jsdomnodejs.JSDOMNodeJSEnv()
```

My question is: How can I do it to have working html page and could run in with sbt without error?

Best regards.